# How to write shaders that can be compiled for DirectX, OpenGL, and Vulkan

Tags: shaders, glsl, hlsl, cg

I recently finished writing the **DirectX** renderer for my game engine.
Now I have an **OpenGL**, **DirectX** as well as a not yet finished **Vulkan** renderer.

Well, the majority of the renderers work perfectly now but I have a problem: I need a **shader programming language**.

The problem is that **OpenGL** and **Vulkan** use *GLSL* but **DirectX** uses *HLSL* (and Apple's **Metal** API uses *MSL*). So I searched for a High Level Shader Language and found only **C for graphics** from NVIDIA. But since this project was deprecated I looked for something else: Without success.

It's a bit annoying to write for 3 shader programming languages at the same time, so I'm looking for a language that can be translated into the native language immediately when the game starts (or is simply compatible with a lot of rendering APIs)

After several weeks of finding nothing, I decided to write my own language for it. But before I invest too much time I want to know if there is another solution to this problem.

Comment: You might be interested in [Google/Angle](https://github.com/google/angle).

Comment: Vulkan doesn't use GLSL but SPIR-V. There is a tool suite which among other useful things contains an offline SPIR-V reference compiler called glslangValidator. No idea about DirectX though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is often solved through the use of a **transpiler**, a program that can translate a shader written in one language into another.

[HLSL2GLSL](https://github.com/aras-p/hlsl2glslfork) is one such example that was used in Unity up until 2016. Shaders could be authored in a standard HLSL syntax, then transpiled at build time into corresponding GLSL code.

[SPIRV-Cross](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/SPIRV-Cross) is another transpiler maintained by the Unity team that can serve as a bridge between HLSL, GLSL, MSL, and Vulkan.

Using an existing shader language as your source helps you avoid the overhead of designing a brand new one from scratch, and you can leverage a lot of work shared by other teams via projects like the ones linked above.

There are some extra considerations though, as outlined in the SPIRV-Cross Readme:

> ### Implementation notes
>
> When using SPIR-V and SPIRV-Cross as an intermediate step for cross-compiling between high level languages there are some considerations to take into account, as not all features used by one high-level language are necessarily supported natively by the target shader language. SPIRV-Cross aims to provide the tools needed to handle these scenarios in a clean and robust way, but some manual action is required to maintain compatibility.

The areas they call out include:

- HLSL source to GLSL

  - HLSL entry points
  - Vertex/Fragment interface linking
- HLSL source to legacy GLSL/ESSL

  - Separate image samplers (HLSL/Vulkan) for backends which do not support it (GLSL)
  - Descriptor sets (Vulkan GLSL) for backends which do not support them (HLSL/GLSL/Metal)
  - Linking by name for targets which do not support explicit locations (legacy GLSL/ESSL)
  - Clip-space conventions
  - Reserved identifiers

See the linked document for all the gory details of how to handle these situations.